# Give another user permission to remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, remote-debugging

Hi I have a IIS server (running on Windows Server 2012 R2), I installed VS2012 remote debugger on it and configure the VS remote debugger run as a service. By default I have debug permission to this IIS server.
Now I want to give another colleague remote debugging permission to my server, but after I spent few hours, I still don't know how to do.

1. Because msvsmon.exe is run as service, it doesn't have UI, how to add another domain joined user?
2. I tried to configure msvsmon.exe run as application, and I added my colleague through its UI, however, after I close msvsmon and restart it, new added user is gone from permission list.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: is VS deployed on the server or do u use remote tools for VS2012?

Comment: And do u explicitly get a premission exception when the user tries to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd (Command line) and add the user to the [remote desktop users](http://www.windows-commandline.com/add-user-to-group-from-command-line/)

```
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" domainname\username /add
```

If that fails, run command line as [administrator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/05cce5f6-3c3a-4bb8-8b72-8c1ce4b5eff1/how-to-run-a-program-as-adminitrator-via-the-command-line?forum=w7itproappcompat) and run the command again